# More pythonic way to manage a list of callbacks

Tags: python, callback

I'm writing a multi-threaded Python application with serial IO, and I have this construct in the IO class:

```
def __init__(self):
    # Register these with thread-safe functions having the arguments listed
    self.callbacks_status = [] # args: (pod_index, message, color)
    self.callbacks_conn   = [] # args: (pod_index, message, color)
    self.callbacks_angle  = [] # args: (pod_index, angle_deg)
    self.callbacks_brake  = [] # args: (brake_on)
```

Then, when one of my updating threads gets a new status, I'm doing something like this every time:

```
        for func in self.callbacks_conn:
            func(i, "Open", "yellow")
```

Needless to say, this is ugly and feels non-pythonic. Is there a more elegant way to call a list of functions with the same arguments? Basically I am looking for the `map` function in reverse.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here, actually.

Comment: I don't see how it's "needless to say". What is non-pythonic about this? BTW, if you have code that works, but you're looking to see if there might be a "better" way of doing it, you should check out the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There is nothing "wrong" with your code, and trying to make it "better" is a pretty subjective idea.

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in "reversed map" function which repeatedly passes a given tuple as an argument to a list of functions. You are free to scour the documentations some more but I think your code looks okay.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I wasn't aware of that exchange. And I guess it isn't as bad as I made it out to be, I just try to avoid using "for" loops for simple operations whenever possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might encapsulate this in a special list with the additional method 'fire', so you can just 'fire' the callback list with some args:

```
class CallbackList(list):
     def fire(self, *args, **kwargs):
         for listener in self:
             listener(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, you manage things like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.callbacks_status = CallbackList()
    self.callbacks_conn = CallbackList()
    self.callbacks_angle = CallbackList()
    self.callbacks_brake = CallbackList()
```

to fire the callback, you'd do:

```
self.callbacks_conn.fire(i, "Open", "yellow")
```

Example usage:

```
>>> def print_double(x):
...     print "%s doubled is %s" % (x, x * 2)
>>> def print_square(x):
...     print "%s squared is %s" % (x, x * x)
>>> cb = CallbackList()
>>> cb.append(print_double)
>>> cb.append(print_square)
>>> cb.fire(8)
8 doubled is 16
8 squared is 64
```

Comment: +1 for extending the list class

Comment: That's a great idea! It's not quite the simple solution I was looking for, but it does solve the problem nicely.